# What can I translate the word "argument" in this passage? What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, translation

The brain is an argument. We make different decisions in different ways. In addition, different parts of the brain respond to stimuli in different time frames. Think of two teams of lawyers doing discovery to prepare for a trial, and you've got the picture. The fMRI scans support the notion put forward by Jonah Lehrer that the brain is an argument. How we settle that argument depends on social context, prior experience, etc.

Comment: The brain is a collection of ideas- often at odds with one another, how one idea is selected depends on social context, prior experience, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They mean that within the brain different processes/parts of the brain interpret things in different ways and then compete (ie argue) with each other to provide the "final"  interpretation or perception.

Comment: Thank you Max
Can you give me a synonym of "argument" and/or its proper definition that suits this context?
I need it for tanslation.

Comment: "debate" is the best option i can think of: this is like an argument but less angry :)  This passage is using a **metaphor** - it's not literally describing what happens in the brain.  So I don't think you will be able to come up with a synonym which really suits this context.